# Use gmail domain account with IMAP authentication with SAML authentication not working

Tags: dns, gmail, imap, saml, account

I have a python script that interfaces gmail accounts and allows searches, etc. This works on normal emails (ending on @gmail.com) but not on domain accounts. In this case authentication is done via SAML, and IMAP is enabled on the gmail domain account...

The instructions from google on how to configure IMAP only seem to work for @gmail.com accounts...

I've tried authentication to IMAP using user, user@admin and using host: imap.gmail.com as well as my domain's email and authentication is not working....

1. is there a specific 'host' from gmail for domain accounts?
2. other way to get imap on gmail domain accounts?

Thanks, 
Rodolfo

Answer (score -2):

RTM:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77654

It should work with:

```
username = username@domain.com
password = password
```